# What constitutes a competitive masters application for a profile geared towards Theoretical CS?

Tags: mathematics, masters, computer-science, theory

I find that there are too few accounts of what constitutes a good TCS profile. I am a math and CS undergrad currently going into my 4th year, and hence am posting here. I am (currently) very interested in computational complexity theory. I have undertaken reading courses and mild research projects in algebra, (quantum) cryptography and algebraic complexity theory. I will be doing another internship next year, and will spend a year doing research before applying. My end goal is to do a PhD from a top university, and do impactful research. I will be graduating top of my class in math, and am maybe in the top 10% in CS.

I find the generic MS profile geared towards AI/ML, and have barely seen any TCS profiles. These applicants have a publication(or two) in decent conferences. However, when I see PhD admits(for TCS) in top universities, they rarely have any publications in their undergrad. So, is that the norm in TCS? Am I at a disadvantage because my profile is not in AI/ML(not that this is going to change anything, I want to pursue only theory, but I want to know what my chances are).

So, I am wondering what a typical masters admit for someone with a TCS profile looks like.